# MySQL Show Null Results in Query - With INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT services.name as Service, services.logo_name as Logo, packages.name as Package 
FROM `client_services` 
INNER JOIN services ON service_id = services.id 
INNER JOIN packages ON packages.id = package_id 
WHERE client_id = 1 
ORDER BY services.sort_id
```

Well in **client_services** I have 5 results that need to be shown.  2 of them are NULL for package_id.  When I run the query, it only shows 3 results, the ones that have a set package_id.

If there is no package, I just want it to show up blank, but the rest of the information is important so I still need the record to show.

[image]

Do I need to change anything in my query to get that to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a `LEFT JOIN`? `LEFT JOIN packages ON packages.id = package_id`

Comment: This behavior is correct for INNER JOIN.  You can get the behavior you want with LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change one line:

```
LEFT JOIN packages ON packages.id = package_id
```